# Some of my outputs doesn't seem to print. How to resolve it?

Tags: java, oop

My code seems to run fine after many changes and improvements. But it still didn't print out all my outputs. How to fix it?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BusPayment {
    public int number_of_adults;
    public int number_of_children;
    public double adult_price;
    public double children_price;
    public double totalprice;

    public BusPayment(){

        }

    public int getnumber_of_adults(){
     return number_of_adults;
       }

    public int getnumber_of_children(){
      return number_of_children;
       }

    public double getadult_price(){
     return adult_price;
       }

    public double getchildren_price(){
      return children_price;
        }

     public double gettotal_price(){
       return totalprice;
        }

      public void setadult_price(double adult_p){
         adult_price=adult_p; 
        }

      public void setchildren_price(double children_p){
          children_price=children_p;
        }

      public void settotalprice(double total_price){
          totalprice=total_price;
         }

      public BusPayment(double adult_p, double children_p){
          adult_price=adult_p;
          children_price=children_p;
          }

       public void BusPaymentPart(){
         number_of_adults=0;
         number_of_children=0;
         adult_price=15.00;
         children_price=10.00;
         totalprice=0.00;
          } 

       public double calculate_totalprice(){
         number_of_adults= 0;
          number_of_children= 0;
         totalprice= (number_of_adults*adult_price)+ 
         (number_of_children*children_price);
         return totalprice;
          }

       public static void main (String []args){
        BusPayment test = new BusPayment();

          Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Payment");
       System.out.println("The price of an adult ticket is 
         15.00.");
           System.out.println("The price of a children's ticket is 
         10.00.");

           int number_of_adults=input.nextInt();
           System.out.println("The number of adults are: " 
           +number_of_adults);
            number_of_adults=input.nextInt();

             int number_of_children=input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number of children are: 
       "+number_of_children);
          number_of_children=input.nextInt();

           double totalpri = test.calculate_totalprice();
          System.out.println("The total price you need to pay: " 
        +totalpri);

         }

       }
```

I wanted it to print:

The price of an adult ticket is 15.00. (this was printed)

The price of a children's ticket is 10.00. (this was printed)

The number of adults are:

The number of children are:

The total price you need to pay:

Comment: Right, it's been a while since my java days. However your script requires some input to actually display anything.  What are you actually inputting? When I try this online I just get errors because there are no inputs. can you add in your arguments please.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and reduce your code to be as minimal as possible

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable and method names are written in camelCase. They start with lowercase and don't contain underscores. Also, you should not make your instance variables public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some additional `input.nextInt()` calls in your main method. If you remove them, the printed values are fine:

```
public static void main (String []args){
    BusPayment test = new BusPayment();

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Payment");
    System.out.println("The price of an adult ticket is 15.00.");
    System.out.println("The price of a children's ticket is 10.00.");

    System.out.println("Enter number of adults:");
    test.number_of_adults=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The number of adults are: "
            +test.number_of_adults);

    System.out.println("Enter number of children:");
    test.number_of_children=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The number of children are:"+test.number_of_children);

    double totalpri = test.calculate_totalprice();
    System.out.println("The total price you need to pay: "
            +totalpri);

}
```

Other problems:

- you're mixing local and instance variables, so that your
  `caldulate_totalprice` is not working - the read values from the
  `stdin` are not propagated to the class. I have fixed that in my
  snippet - you might want to create a setter for that as well/pass constructor parameter
- remove the `number_of_adults=0;` and `number_of_children=0;` from your `calculate_totalprice` method.
- initialize the ticket price in constructor, or call `BusPaymentPart` method manually

Comment: Thank you @Ondra K. ! But the calculate_totalprice is still not working. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Did you do the steps I mentioned in second and third bullet point? Because I managed to get it working.

Comment: Alright thank you! It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your problem, the fact that the 2 first print occur is because they are before the "input.nextInt()"

Input.nextInt() is used when you want to ask the user to give your program data.

Therefore here it is waiting for some input in the console, try entering 5 and you Will see the next print.

Hope it helps